# WebOs confusion ! Should i use PhoneGap or WebOs SDK?

Tags: cordova, webos

i am new to webos and, i want to start with PhoneGap but i have confusion is that
PhoneGaP covered all the feature which webos providing ?
Can we build professional Apps for WebOs in PhoneGap ?

And as you know if phonegap is batter then we have more chances to open other phone development door !

Comment: At least in theory, PhoneGap should work great on webOS since it's already working in JavaScript.  Of course, the reality may be that PhoneGap doesn't support everything, but it should be relatively easy to add any missing functionality because it's all just JavaScript, no compiled libraries needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was investigating the same thing those days and my conclusion is: NO (and yes).

If you use a lib for GUI **other than enyo** you should port it using phonegap to whatever (Android?), but if you use the enyo lib phonegap doesn't help at all, and your are developing a "native" app.

I was testing with JQuery mobile, Sencha Touch and others, and I'll do my app with enyo and forget phonegap for the moment.

Comment: me too think ... as like and now using enyo. have you any book or website link to  start with ENYO?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we build professional Apps for WebOs in PhoneGap?

Yes. You don't need it though. PhoneGap makes the packaging of the app much easier though.

I have written a tutorial on using PhoneGap & plain javascript, to create your webOS app:

http://www.anthonybennis.com/blog/packing-html5-application-for-a-webos-hp-touchpad-device/